# Scheduling and configuring parse jobs for users

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm using Twilio for my website and parse as a backend for a POC I'm working on. 
I have the following scenario:

- User signs up - I store user in parse - I send them a text at a later date depending on their profile.

I am able to schedule system wide jobs which run for a give time.

Is it possible to assign a job to an individual user with a time frame?

E.g

Schedule a job for User1 a week from now

Schedule a job for User2 a day from now etc.

Answer (score 0):

I know its not exactly what you asked but why not just have a batch job that runs every hour (or whatever frequency you want). It can pick up all the users and look at their profile and decide whether to send them a text or not.

Comment: I've thought of that but that's my last resort, i wanted a more efficient solution.